# Error with typhoeus/faraday adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, faraday, typhoeus

My app uses panda for video embedding. I have created the panda.rb initializer and the panda.yml file inside config. I am able to connect to panda (fire up the rails console). When I do Panda::Profile.all, I get the following error:

```
   1.8.7-p371 :001 > Panda::Profile.all
   Ethon::Errors::InvalidOption: The option: disable_ssl_peer_verification is invalid.
   Please try ssl_verifypeer instead of disable_ssl_peer_verification.
   from /home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/ethon-0.5.10/lib/ethon/easy.rb:255:in 
   `set_attributes'
   from /home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/ethon-0.5.10/lib/ethon/easy.rb:253:in 
   `each_pair'
```

Based on the changes suggested for typhoeus for this error msg at
         https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/issues/226#issuecomment-9919517

I added the line require 'typhoeus/adapters/faraday' inside easy.rb (home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/ethon-0.5.10/easy.rb)

However now I am getting the below error, when I try to do rails c:

```
      /home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/typhoeus-
      0.6.2/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb:19: undefined method `supports_parallel=' 
      for Faraday::Adapter::Typhoeus:Class (NoMethodError)
      from /home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/ethon-.5.10/lib/ethon/easy.rb:11:in   
      `require'
  from /home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/ethon-0.5.10/lib/ethon/easy.rb:11
  from /home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/ethon-0.5.10/lib/ethon.rb:9:in 
      `require'
```

A look at the list of gems in my app shows that it is using the following:
          ethon (0.5.10)
          faraday (0.7.6)
          typhoeus (0.6.2)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the panda version to '1.6.0' and adding api_port 80 to my panda.yml, I was able to get this working